# How to write the final dense layer to "accept" (x,y) tuples

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

TL;DR:
Have input `(batch_size,128,60,41,2)` and labels `(batch_size, 128)`, each label is either 0, 1, or 2. How should network output be/how to design output?

I am converting audio clips of length 60 seconds each to an array of `(128, 60, 41, 2)`*. This is my feature data per example.

As for the labels, I have (per example) and array of shape `(128,)`, for each of the 128 things I extract.

So one (feature, label) pair is int the form `(feature={128, 60, 41,2}, label={128})`.

When I batch the data, the features and labels get appended to; e.g. for a batch of size 10: the features are of shape: `(10,128,60,41,2)`, and labels are of shape `(10,128)`

My clarified question is: How can I design the network to calculate a loss based on this labels?

The longer version:
The last dense layer should have `3` units, one per class. Now, I have a batch with `bs` items. Thus, I have labels in the shape `(bs,128)`. How can the network be designed to calculate the loss; the first batch item is of shape `(128,60,41,2)`, and the labels for this first item are in shape `(128,)`. Each label within is either 0, 1, or 2. Now I want to calculate to design the network to have as the last output a shape of `(None, 128,3)`.

None is the batch size, 128 for all the things I extract, and the 3 because I have three classes

---

Edit: Thanks for the notes, I hopefully clarified the question

*For those further interested:
I use a sliding window over the time axis. For each window, I extract log-scaled spectrograms. Here, 128 is the number of windows, 60 and 41 control the Mel scale, and 2 is for adding a delta dimension.

The code to generate the audio:

```py
def sub_method(fn, label, bands, frames, delta):
  
  def _windows(data, window_size):
        start = 0
        while start < len(data):
            yield int(start), int(start + window_size)
            start += (window_size // 2)

  window_size = 512 * (frames - 1)
  segment_log_specgrams, segment_labels = [], []
  sound_clip,sr = librosa.load(fn)
  for (start,end) in _windows(sound_clip,window_size):
      if(len(sound_clip[start:end]) == window_size):
          signal = sound_clip[start:end]
          melspec = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(signal,n_mels=bands)
          logspec = librosa.amplitude_to_db(melspec)
          logspec = logspec.T.flatten()[:, np.newaxis].T
          segment_log_specgrams.append(logspec)
          segment_labels.append(label)


  if delta:
    segment_log_specgrams = np.asarray(segment_log_specgrams)
    segment_log_specgrams = segment_log_specgrams.reshape(len(segment_log_specgrams),bands,frames,1)    
    segment_features = np.concatenate((segment_log_specgrams, np.zeros(np.shape(segment_log_specgrams))), axis=3)
    for i in range(len(segment_features)):
      segment_features[i, :, :, 1] = librosa.feature.delta(segment_features[i, :, :, 0])
  else:
    segment_features = segment_log_specgrams

  if len(segment_features) > 0: # check for empty segments
    return 1, segment_features, segment_labels
  else:
    return 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: You've told us what you have (sorta, there's a lot of audio processing jargon to get through for a question targeted at NN folks) but haven't given us much of an idea of what you want or how you think you might get there.

Comment: @DanielF, i clarified the question. Is there a chance of you (or someone else) reopening it? I'd prefer avoiding opening a new question to reduce spam. Thanks.

Comment: the description of the problem looks similar to [multilabel classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/MultiLabelHead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Reshape
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential

model = Sequential([
  Reshape((128, -1), input_shape=(128, 60, 41, 2)),
  Dense(3)
])

inp = tf.random.uniform([10, 128, 60, 41, 2], dtype=tf.float32)
labels = tf.random.uniform([10, 128], 0, 3, dtype=tf.int32)
pred = model(inp)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(inp, labels)
```

Comment: This solved my problem. I used your proposed Reshape operation as the second-to-last layer in my network. Thanks.